# How many lumens are there in one watt?

Tags: electrical

I have a problem to sale electric lamp and LED bulb. So I want to know how many lumens equal to how many watts?

Answer (score 5):

This depends completely upon what method is used to convert the electrical energy into light.  Is it an old Edison bulb (incandescent), florescent, LED, something else?

It will also vary significantly within each type.  Not all LED bulbs are equally efficient.  There simply isn't any direct conversion.  You need to check the specs for the specific bulbs you are comparing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct lumen to watt conversion. The efficiency of the lamp must be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a pretty good table of [Lumens per watt for various light types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_efficacy#Examples_2).
If you've got something exotic, there are [many other such tables online](https://www.google.com/search?q=lumens%20per%20watt%20table&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=5ENsVbr4NMPaoASctIPgAw&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1124&bih=591).